# slice pandas dataframe by column showing all except the column provided

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have a dataframe (df) which looks like this

```
category | amount | freq
green         10     1
blue          5      2
orange        7      3
purple        5      4
```

I want to select only the 'frequency' and 'amount' columns, and all rows except the purple one

I know I can use df.ix to select the columns like this

```
df.ix[['green','blue','orange'],['freq','amount']]
```

However, how do you get the unique values in the category column, and select the columns which are not purple?

```
df.set_index(['category'])
```

**Update**

See Roman Pekar's solution for filtering out rows that you don't want.

For multiple rows create a series or a list (i.e. account_group) and reference it like this.

```
names = sorted_data[sorted_data.account.isin(account_group)]
```

Done this way **names** is a dataframe.

However this is similar but incorrect syntax, this will return a series.

```
names = sorted_data['account'].isin(account_group)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> df
  category  amount  freq
0    green      10     1
1     blue       5     2
2   orange       7     3
3   purple       5     4

>>> df[df['category'] != 'purple'][['amount','freq']]
   amount  freq
0      10     1
1       5     2
2       7     3
```

**update** not sure if I understood OP correctly, but he wants also do it *`by subtracting lists: the first list is all the rows in the dataframe, the second is purple, and the third would be list-one minus list-two which would be green, blue, orange`*. Hence another solution:

```
>>> l1
['green', 'blue', 'orange', 'purple']
>>> l2
['purple']
>>> l3 = [x for x in l1 if x not in l2]
>>> l3
['green', 'blue', 'orange']
>>> df[df['category'].isin(l3)][['amount','freq']]
   amount  freq
0      10     1
1       5     2
2       7     3
```

Comment: Thanks Roman Pekar, could it also be done by subtracting lists: the first list is all the rows in the dataframe, the second is purple, and the third would be list-one minus list-two which would be green, blue, orange? Is this possible?

Comment: is it possible to filter the columns as well in the same operation where the are sliced like: "df[df['category'] != 'purple'][['amount','freq'==[3,5]]]"

Comment: you can do it like this `df[(df['category'] == 'blue') & (df['amount'] == 5) & (df['freq'] == 2)]`

Comment: is it possble to do the same as in your answer but make it !="category1","category2","category3"

Comment: ~df['category'].isin("category1","category2","category3")

Comment: this returns a series, I was expecting it to return a dataframe with only those categories in the category column of the dataframe?